# Test POST request, with session and controller instance.

Tags: java, scala, session, testing, playframework

I am trying to test my Play Application controller, but am struggling to find away to have the test return both session data while utilising an instance of the controller.

```
public class HomeControllerTest extends WithApplication {

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
            .configure("play.http.router", "router.Routes")
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGameChoiceHvH() {
        Map form = new HashMap<String, String>();
        form.put("gameType", "0");
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        Result result = invokeWithContext(fakeRequest().bodyForm(form),
            () -> homeController.chooseGame());
        assertEquals(SEE_OTHER, result.status());
        assertEquals("/play", result.header("Location").get());
        assertFalse(result.session().isEmpty());
        String gameId = result.session().get("game_id");
        assertTrue(homeController.getGame(gameId).getCurrentPlayer() instanceof Human);
    }

}
```

The final assertion here is simulating taking the gameId stored in the session and using it retrieve the game instance, created in the controller action and stored in a Map within the controller instance. The issue is that by using invokeWithContext, the `result` does not contain the Cookie object at all, so it cannot be retrieved.

The alternative method I have found to create a post request is the following:

```
public class HomeControllerTest extends WithApplication {

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
            .configure("play.http.router", "router.Routes")
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGameChoiceHvH() {
        Map form = new HashMap<String, String>();
        form.put("gameType", "0");
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        Result result = route(fakeRequest(routes.HomeController.chooseGame()).bodyForm(form));
        assertEquals(SEE_OTHER, result.status());
        assertEquals("/play", result.header("Location").get());
        assertFalse(result.session().isEmpty());
        String gameId = result.session().get("game_id");
        assertTrue(homeController.getGame(gameId).getCurrentPlayer() instanceof Human);
    }

}
```

However, this obviously means that the final assertion is looking at a new instance of the HomeController, not the one used by the `route` function, so as such, the Map is empty.

For clarity, here is the relevant controller code:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private WebInterface ui = new WebInterface();
    private Map<String, Board> boardMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Game> gameMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Game getGame(String gameId) {
        return gameMap.get(gameId);
    }

    public Result chooseGame() {
        Map<String, String[]> request = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        Board board = new Board();
        Game game = new Game(new PlayerFactory(ui).create(GameType.values()[Integer.valueOf(request.get("gameType")[0])]));
        boardMap.put(Integer.toString(board.hashCode()), board);
        gameMap.put(Integer.toString(game.hashCode()), game);
        session("game_id", Integer.toString(game.hashCode()));
        session("board_id", Integer.toString(board.hashCode()));
        return redirect("/play");
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, after too long looking for a solution to this, I found the answer in the source code:

```
/**
 * Calls a Callable which invokes a Controller or some other method with a Context
 */
public static <V> V invokeWithContext(RequestBuilder requestBuilder, Callable<V> callable) {
  try {
    Context.current.set(new Context(requestBuilder));
    return callable.call();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    Context.current.remove();
  }
}
```

Based on this, information, it is now obvious why invokeWithContext doesn't expose the context after it is run. So as a quick and dirty implementation of a solution:

```
@Test
public void testGameChoiceHvH() {
    Map form = new HashMap<String, String>();
    form.put("gameType", "0");
    HomeController homeController = new HomeController();

    Http.RequestBuilder request = fakeRequest(routes.HomeController.chooseGame()).bodyForm(form);
    try {
        Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context(request));
        homeController.chooseGame();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

        assertFalse(Http.Context.current().session().isEmpty());
        String gameId = Http.Context.current().session().get("game_id");

        assertTrue(homeController.getGame(gameId).getCurrentPlayer() instanceof DelayedComputer);

        Http.Context.current.remove();
    }
}
```

This exposes both the session, and the homeController instance, so the assertions can both be tested.